# How to connect panel and translated panel after 'Add translation' node?

Tags: panels, i18n-l10n

I translate the panel node by selecting Add translation. After doing this, I setup the panel title, layout etc. Press save, but I then end up with two nodes which aren't connected, ie. switching languages doesn't work. Then, going to the translation still shows the 'Add translation' link! This isn't the case for my other content types.

The only way around this at the moment is to manually couple the two translations together by entering the translated node's title in the 'SELECT TRANSLATIONS FOR' autocomplete search field.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late, but just in case you still need it: http://drupal.org/node/1994046